# How to remove the spaces between the form and the footer as shown below in the picture?

Tags: css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA3ia.png)

See i have fixed the position of the footer but still the space is there between the footer and the form so i need to solution to this problem and remove these extra spaces . I am facing this both in the desktop view as well as mobile so i need the solution of this as soon as possible.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please click on the link shown above

Comment: I have attached an image link please check that link

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. We can't help without seeing your code, see what you have tried. The image isn't enough to help.

We need your HTML and CSS code

Comment: Here css code:border: yellow 0px solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #232023;
    margin-top: 1010px;

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You did not add your code so I think that footer has position: absolute there . You must delete position: absolute rule from you CSS of you footer . Another Solution is that maybe you have `min-height` on your content section , so you must change it on `height: auto` . Without your code we cannot give you better answer